# Supervisor/Gunicorn/Nginx/Flask - 500 error

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm having a hard time troubleshooting this error.

I'll try to outline the context as good as possible and at the end of my question I'll provide the contents of all config files.

I'm using gunicorn to power up my Flask application and Ngninx handles the proxy proxy_pass.

If I'm manually running `gunicorn run:app --log-level=debug --log-file=/tmp/test_gunicorn65.log` the application is served when accessing http://my_pretty_dns

At the same time, if i'm trying to run gunicorn through supervisor, the server throws 500 Internal Server Error

My nginx conf:

```
server {
    server_name test.something.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

My supervisor conf:

```
[program:something]
command = /home/ubuntu/work/repos/something/gunicorn_start_project
directory = /home/ubuntu/work/repos/something 
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisor_stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisor_stderr.log
user = ubuntu
```

Contents of gunicorn_start_project:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec venv/bin/gunicorn run:app --log-level=debug --log-file=/tmp/test_gunicorn65.log
```

tl;dr: Not sure why the application is served when gunicorn is powered manually from CLI and when powered by supervisor it throws 'Internal Server Error'.

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: The only thing which I can see in my nginx error.log is something along this lines: 14270#14270: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: my.ip.address, server: my.host.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "my.host.com". Not sure what's causing this or if this is the reason of my error. I don't get anything like this when running gunicorn manually.

Comment: Where in your configuration does it tell Gunicorn / your app to host a server on port 8000? From the server (or using an SSH proxy) try connecting to the socket directly (e.g. `nc localhost 8000` then type `GET / HTTP/1.1 \n Host: my.host.com \n \n`)

Comment: @Alex, replace `\n` with newlines (Enter).